# How to empty product name from duplicate rows

Tags: mysql

Can you help me with mysql query ? I would like to empty all duplicated product name and keep ONLY one row (product name and its SKU).

I wrote the query like this. Can you please confirm If it's the right syntax

```
UPDATE tvcom_product t1 JOIN 
  (SELECT name
   FROM tvcom_product
   GROUP BY name
   HAVING count(product_id) > 1) dup ON t1.name = dup.name
SET t1.name = '' WHERE t1.sku != ''
```

Comment: what's the error?

Comment: just curious... y don't you do it by array operations?

Comment: Because I have about 30000 products and a lot of them are duplicated. The script works but I am not sure It s correct script or not ?

Comment: This sql reset all record.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sql
UPDATE tvcom_product t1 
JOIN tvcom_product t2 ON t2.name = t1.name AND t2.sku < t1.sku
SET t1.name = ''
```

This will reset `name` for all the records which have duplicates with same name. It will leave just one record with the smallest (alphabetically) SKU.
Instead of `t2.sku < t1.sku` you can write `t2.id < t1.id` - should be more optimal, it will leave out the record with smallest ID.

**Upd.** This is simplest but not most optimal way. For huge tables this one should work better:

```sql
UPDATE tvcom_product t1 
JOIN (
    SELECT name, MIN(id) id
    FROM tvcom_product
    GROUP BY name
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) t2 ON t1.name = t2.name AND t1.id != t2.id
SET t1.name = ''
```

If you want to optimise it even more then you should store the sub-query in a separate table and join it. Of course `id` in this query can be changed with `sku`.